# Error in xcdatamodel

Tags: ios, xcode, xcdatamodel

My xcdatamodel file in Xcode seems to be behaving weirdly.

When I build my project for the first time it gives an error

```
"Unable to write VersionInfo.plist for the versioned model at <Path>"
```

and

```
"Compilation failed for data model at path <Path>"
```

But when I run it again, it runs without an error. 
Then after some time the error pops up again and again vanishes when I build again. 
Sometimes I get a different error message which says

Unable to remove existing model

Any Ideas ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not create bundle folder for versioned model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230297/could-not-create-bundle-folder-for-versioned-model)

Comment: @evanescent Were you able to fix this issue? I am getting the exact same error-message in XCode 7.2.1

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this same error, then eventually also got the error mentioned in [this other question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230297/could-not-create-bundle-folder-for-versioned-model#answer-16139661).  After following the suggestion in this answer, the error seems to have gone away:

**Solution 1:**

**Delete the following directory:**

```
/Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-of-app-gfofxrkhgcfgcfecjrnbbgyowlnf
```

I later got the same error where this first solution didn't work.  This time the following solution worked instead:

**Solution 2:**

**Recursively set the permissions to 777 for this directory:**

```
chmod -R 777 /Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/name-of-app-gfofxrkhgcfgcfecjrnbbgyowlnf
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Remove derived data:
**Windows** > **Projects** > **Select your project** > **Derived Data** > **Delete**

**2.** Clean your project.

It should work. If still not working,

**3.** Run the project continuously (This actually had worked for me..)

Hope it works !!!